# Will using margin always lower my sharpe ratio

Tags: margin

Are there any good books/resources there that advise on guidelines on how to best use margin?
Most advice about using a broker's margin goes like this 'Margin is risky. Only for experienced investors. The End'.

But margin has been around for a while, so clearly someone has found out how to best use it and have shared their wisdom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could borrow at the risk-free rate using margin would not lower your Sharpe ratio.  When you scaled up your portfolio using leverage the returns would scale up at the same rate as the volatility and the Sharpe ratio would remain constant

Many institutional investors use margin either explicitly or implicitly though derivatives.  As these larger investors can borrow at near the risk free rate margin can be used to scale up their expected risk and return at only a small cost.  However, for individual investors the interest rate for this borrowing is often large.  Even a relatively good [6% interest rate](http://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/investing/accounts_products/investment/margin_accounts) will wipe out most long-term investment gains.

While a quick Google search will turn up a ton of articles on margin few of them will give guidelines and for good reason.  In good times margin investing is very easy to understand you just subtract the margin costs from the gains on the margin amount and get a feel for if you will make any money.   However, understanding how margin will effect your portfolio in bad times is very difficult.

Essentially, the main issue is that margin can [force you to sell](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/margincall.asp) near the bottom of the market during a crash if you can't raise the cash to cover the margin call.  Many people do try to understand their cash situation in a crisis, but since these crashes are so infrequent and each one is different this can be very difficult and many hedge funds fail due to running too near the edge.

So some basic guidelines might be

- Make sure that you have a significantly higher expected return than your margin costs
- Make sure that you would have enough cash to cover the margin call a bad crisis
- Make sure that any added cash (or cash-like investments) you keep aside doesn't eat into the return so much that the returns aren't less than your margin costs...

You can see why the standard advice for individual investors is "don't use margin."